# Is there an upper limit on the CompletableFuture tasks created under ForkPoolJoin executer?

Tags: java, threadpool, completable-future, forkjoinpool

I have written a job which creates a high level of tasks, and is using completable futures to execute these tasks.

By default I found out that ForkJoinPool will be used as the executor, and it creates threads equal to the number of hardware threads available.

So I am not concerned about the number of threads reaching a high number. But the management of these tasks, might also lead to some issues. Any pointers regarding whether there is an upper limit on the number of tasks (small or big) managed by CompletableFuture / ForkPoolJoin?